# React function with if else statements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm very new to React. I'm trying to convert a bit of javascript into React.

It is for a barcode and I'm trying to control the width of the barcode by counting the chars in the generated string. This code works well in JS, but only for one value.

```
var generatedBarcode = '1234567890' // create barcode chars
            
var charCount = (`${generatedBarcode.length}`); // count barcode chars
console.log(charCount)

        if (charCount == 9){var barcodeWidth = 2.60;}
        else if (charCount == 10){var barcodeWidth = 2.38;}
        else if (charCount == 11){var barcodeWidth = 2.24;}
        else if (charCount == 12){var barcodeWidth = 2.10;}
        else if (charCount == 13){var barcodeWidth = 1.95;}
        else if (charCount == 14){var barcodeWidth = 1.85;} // etc. I have worked out the widths
        else {var barcodeWidth = 0.75;};
```

I'd very much like to turn this code into a function so that I can generate multiple barcodes on a page and for each (with a different character length) work out the appropriate width.

If you can point me in the right direction, I'd be very grateful. I'm desperately trying to get my head around React!

Thanks very much!

Comment: It's time to [stop using var](https://dev.to/mindninjax/stop-using-var-for-declaring-variables-2p3a). Also, there's nothing about React in this question.

Comment: Also, why are you converting `generatedBarcode.length` into a string and then  comparing that against numbers e.g. `if (charCount == 9)`? Just compare the numeric `generatedBarcode.length` against the desired length.

Answer (score 1):

Add your widths to array, and just call the function that returns your width. If your barcode starts with length of 9, just change `[barcode.length]` to `[barcode.length - 9]`

```
const barcodeWidths = [2.6, 2.38, 2.24, 2.1, 1.95, 1.85, ...etc.]

const getBarcodeWidth = (barcode) => {
   return barcodeWidths[barcode.length]
}
```

Comment: So, if I have 3 barcodes: 

bacode01 = 12345
barcode02 = 1234567
barcode03  = 1234567890

how do I call the function for each on the page? (sorry, I'm being dense)

Comment: `const barcodeWidth1 = getBarcodeWidth(barcode01)`
`const barcodeWidth2 = getBarcodeWidth(barcode02)`
`const barcodeWidth3 = getBarcodeWidth(barcode03)`

But it would be better if you put them in an array and then loop through them

Comment: I think I'm confusing the issue... I don't know what the barcodes will be. I only know the width of the barcode depending on the number of chars in the string. So if barcode01 is 12chars long, I know it's width is 2.10. I have all the widths programmed into the array, so the 12th one is 2.10. The above code throws an error on: const getBarcodeWidth=(barcode) => { with the error arrow pointing up on the b

Comment: Probably needs to return a default of 0.75 for any barcode width >= barcodeWidths.length.